# how to get a list of activities with their details from some created activity new fields

Tags: activities, reports

I need to get a report of activities listed with some extra fields I created for the activity layout.
Ex:

Type of activity: MEASUREMENTS.

I created 2 new fields called "high" and "weight" assigned to that type of activity.
Now, I need to get a list of every activity recorded, with the "high" and weight" for every activity listed in the report.

Any ideas, guys.

Answer (score 1):

For those custom fields make sure the "is this field searchable" box is checked.

Then under reports - contact reports there's one called activity detail. In there you'll see a section to include your fields in the report.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!!. So excited to try it straight on. I'll comment on the results here when it's done.  Many thanks again!,